# Share launch screen across multiple Projects in Swift

Tags: swift, uistoryboard, viewcontroller

I am building 50 City information apps, all of the apps are identical in structure etc. The only difference is the city specific information that will be displayed in each.

I would like to be able to create a Main Storyboard and view controller in a shared library (framework) and then each app would launch that screen and associated code on start up.

Otherwise if I decide to change the layout or code of my main screen, I would need to change it across 50 projects!

Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Why would you create 50 different apps if they have a similar format and structure?

The best way to go about this would be to simply create one application with several data sources.

Comment: I need 50 apps in the App Store, not one app that does everything.

Example, London City Guide, New York City Guide, Tokyo City Guide and so on.

Each app would share a huge amount of the same code.

Do you know how to do what I am asking about?